# Win32Api windows move

Tags: winapi

how i can move my window when middle mouse button pressed?

in case with left mouse button it would be

```
case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
{
    SendMessage(hwnd, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HTCAPTION, 0);
}
return 0;
```

but it does not work with middle button

```
 case WM_MBUTTONDOWN:
    {
        SendMessage(hwnd, WM_NCMBUTTONDOWN, HTCAPTION, 0);
    }
return 0;
```

but i am not sure about  WM_NCMBUTTONDOWN

i`m out of variants, need help please

Comment: Blindly changing code you do not understand will not produce a robust solution. The code is wrong in both cases. Handle the [WM_NCHITTEST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/inputdev/wm-nchittest) message instead.

Comment: You say you want to move the window with a middle button click but then talk about the right button not working, which is it that you want? The middle button gets its own messages.

Comment: Sorry, my bad i  tested with Rbutton and forget to change, but
case WM_MBUTTONDOWN:
    {
        SendMessage(hwnd, WM_NCMBUTTONDOWN, HTCAPTION, 0);
    }
return 0;
not work too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do this the hard way I'm afraid.  I tried all the obvious things and WM_NCHITTEST doesn't cut it if you want to drag the window with anything other than the left mouse button.

Here's some code that works for me (tested on Windows 10).  I've excluded error checking for brevity:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h>
#include <tchar.h>

// WndProc
LRESULT CALLBACK MyWndProc (HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static int xClick, yClick;

    switch (uMsg)
    {
        case WM_NCMBUTTONDOWN:
        case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
        case WM_MBUTTONDOWN:
        {
            SetCapture (hWnd);
            POINT pt = { GET_X_LPARAM (lParam), GET_Y_LPARAM (lParam) };
            if (uMsg == WM_NCMBUTTONDOWN)
                ScreenToClient (hWnd, &pt);
            xClick = pt.x;
            yClick = pt.y;
            return 0;
        }

        case WM_LBUTTONUP:
        case WM_MBUTTONUP:
            ReleaseCapture ();
            return 0;

        case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
        {
            if (GetCapture() == hWnd)
            {
                RECT wr;
                GetWindowRect (hWnd, &wr);
                int xMouse = GET_X_LPARAM (lParam);
                int yMouse = GET_Y_LPARAM (lParam);
                int xWindow = wr.left + xMouse - xClick;
                int yWindow = wr.top + yMouse - yClick;
                SetWindowPos (hWnd, NULL ,xWindow, yWindow, 0, 0 , SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER);
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return DefWindowProc (hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}


// WinMain
int CALLBACK _tWinMain (HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPTSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    HINSTANCE hInstance = NULL;
    WNDCLASS wc = { };
    wc.lpszClassName = __T ("MyWindowClass");
    wc.lpfnWndProc = MyWndProc;
    RegisterClass (&wc);
    HWND hWnd = CreateWindow (wc.lpszClassName, __T ("My Window"),
        WS_CAPTION | WS_BORDER | WS_VISIBLE, 100, 100, 200, 200, NULL, NULL, hInstance, 0);

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage (&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
        DispatchMessage (&msg);
    return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps.